# PHP Form Not Processing Text Field Inputs

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a pretty basic signup form on WordPress page that captures a name, email, and phone number; and then process the output using a PHP script that I've used several times in the past.

When submitting the form, the user is taken to the landing page, the admin notification is sent, and the data is dumped to the csv file. The problem is that the inputted values are not populating where they are supposed to, so the email looks like this:

```
A new user has submitted a form:

First Name :
Last Name :
Email :
Phone : 

Sent 05/29/14, 12:18:28 PM, from 68.51.108.161 (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36).
```

Likewise, the csv file has no form input data, just the separators and the meta data:

```
"","","","","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36","68.51.108.161","2014-05-29","13:29:34"
```

The user email is not sent out at all.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="form-body">
    <form action="http://domain.com/register.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-upper">
            <h5 class="text-white left">First</h5>
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input name="FirstName" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-upper">
            <h5 class="text-white left">Last</h5>
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input name="LastName" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-upper">
            <h5 class="text-white left">Email</h5>
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input name="Emails" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-upper">
            <h5 class="text-white left">Phone</h5>
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input name="Phones" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form-button">
            <h5><button type="submit">SEND</button></h5>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here's the script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('track_errors', true);

function DoStripSlashes($fieldValue)
{

    // temporary fix for PHP6 compatibility - magic quotes deprecated in PHP6

    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        if (is_array($fieldValue)) {
            return array_map('DoStripSlashes', $fieldValue);
        }
        else {
            return trim(stripslashes($fieldValue));
        }
    }
    else {
        return $fieldValue;
    }
}

function FilterCChars($theString)
{
    return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]/', '', $theString);
}

function ProcessTABCVSField($theString, $textSeparator)
{
    if ($textSeparator == 'tab') {
        $theString = preg_replace('/\t/', ' ', $theString);
    }

    $theString = preg_replace('/\"/', '""', $theString);
    return $theString;
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$FTGFirstName = DoStripSlashes($_POST['FirstName']);
$FTGLastName = DoStripSlashes($_POST['LastName']);
$FTGEmails = DoStripSlashes($_POST['Emails']);
$FTGPhones = DoStripSlashes($_POST['Phones']);
$validationFailed = false;

// Include message in error page and dump it to the browser

if ($validationFailed === true) {
    $errorPage = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Error</title></head><body><!--VALIDATIONERROR--></body></html>';
    $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:FirstName-->', $FTGFirstName, $errorPage);
    $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:LastName-->', $FTGLastName, $errorPage);
    $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:Emails-->', $FTGEmails, $errorPage);
    $errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:Phones-->', $FTGPhones, $errorPage);
    $errorList = @implode("<br />\n", $FTGErrorMessage);
    $errorPage = str_replace('<!--VALIDATIONERROR-->', $errorList, $errorPage);
    if (count(array_filter($FTGErrorMessage)) > 0) {
        foreach($FTGErrorMessage as $key => $message) {
            $ErrorMessage.= trim(str_replace("'", "\'", $message)) . '\n';
        }

        $alertJSErrorMessage = "window.alert('" . $ErrorMessage . "');";
        $onloadPattern = '/(<body[^>]+onload=[\"]*)"([^>]*)>/i';
        if (preg_match($onloadPattern, $errorPage)) {
            $replacementPattern = '\1"' . $alertJSErrorMessage . '\2>';
        }
        else {
            $onloadPattern = '/(<body[^>]*)>/i';
            $replacementPattern = '\1 onload="' . $alertJSErrorMessage . '">';
        }

        $errorPage = preg_replace($onloadPattern, $replacementPattern, $errorPage);
    }

    echo $errorPage;
}

if ($validationFailed === false) {

    // Email to Form Owner

    $emailSubject = FilterCChars("Website Registration");
    $emailBody = "A new user has submitted a form:\n" . "\n" . "First Name : $FTGFirstName\n" . "Last Name : $FTGLastName\n" . "Email : $FTGEmails\n" . "Phone : $FTGPhones\n" . "\n" . "Sent " . date('m/d/y') . ", " . date('h:i:s A') . ", from $clientIP (" . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . ").";
    $emailTo = 'Someone <myemail@foo.bar>,Another <hisemail@bar.foo>';
    $emailFrom = FilterCChars("$FTGEmails");
    $emailHeader = "From: $emailFrom\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit\n";
    mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody, $emailHeader);

    // ====================================================
    // Dump field values to a text file=
    // ====================================================

    $fileDump = 'registrations.txt';
    unset($dumpHeader);
    if (!file_exists($fileDump)) {
        $dumpHeader = sprintf("\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"", ProcessTABCVSField('FirstName', kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , ProcessTABCVSField('LastName', kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , ProcessTABCVSField('Emails', kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , ProcessTABCVSField('Phones', kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , "HTTP_USER_AGENT", "CLIENT_IP", "DATE", "TIME");
        $dumpHeader.= "\n";
    }

    $fileHandle = @fopen($fileDump, 'a');
    if ($fileHandle === false) {
        echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Error</title></head><body><b>Text Dump Error</b>: Cannot write to the text file: <b>' . $fileDump . '</b><br />. Script will quit now.</body></html>';
        if (ini_get('track_errors')) {
            echo '<b>PHP Error</b>: ' . $php_errormsg;
        }

        exit;
    }

    $dumpRecord = sprintf("\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"", ProcessTABCVSField($FTGFirstName, kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , ProcessTABCVSField($FTGLastName, kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , ProcessTABCVSField($FTGEmails, kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , ProcessTABCVSField($FTGPhones, kTextDumpFieldSeparator) , $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $clientIP, date('Y-m-d') , date('H:i:s'));
    $dumpRecord = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $dumpRecord);
    $dumpRecord = str_replace("\r", "\\r", $dumpRecord);
    $dumpRecord = $dumpRecord . "\n";
    if (strlen($dumpHeader) > 0) {
        fwrite($fileHandle, $dumpHeader);
    }

    fwrite($fileHandle, $dumpRecord);
    fclose($fileHandle);

    // Redirect user to success page

    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/thank-you/");
}

?>
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: it's your $validationFailed variable. When it is set to false, it works perfectly on my local test machine. When I set it to true, an error is thrown for $FTGErrorMessage as being null.

Comment: $validationFailed is already set to false, though.

Comment: When $validationFailed is set to false, it is working perfectly on my local test machine. However, when you set it to true or you comment out the variable in your php, it fails immediately.

Comment: I completely removed the validation conditionals and still am having no success.

Comment: Then your not receiving anything from your $POST super global and it's not the form that is the problem. check your post_max_size value in your php.ini

Comment: What happens if you comment out everything on the PHP page and just print_r($_POST)

Comment: It outputs "Array ()" (see thread below).

Comment: Your $_POST is being filtered before it gets to your processor.

Comment: That's what we've determined on our end, too. WP apparently requires you to use their post hooks, and filters out any that don't conform, presumably for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your PHP.

My guess is that there is an error in your form...

Instead of:

```
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
```

Try:

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND">
```

And in PHP debug the posted values with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and report what you get (before and after the modification).

Comment: After changing it to input, print_r output "Array ()"

Comment: Same goes for button, print_r outputs "Array()"

Comment: OK so if the $_POST superglobal is empty it means that the HTML don't post correctly your input fields...

Comment: Does your `form action` value is the PHP snippet you posted?

Comment: Yes, it is. All of the PHP code is working, I just can't get the values to post. Is it possible something within WP is intercepting that data?

Comment: Yes it can be this... Maybe this can help (I don't know WP that much): http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data